# Cant sendKeys into ebay username field using WebDriver Selenium 3 with Java and chrome

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

I have been unable to sendKeys text into the username and password field on ebay.

Here is the code:

```
    WebDriver driver = null;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.ebay.co.uk");

    WebElement myEbay = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My eBay"));
    myEbay.click();

    WebElement signInForm = driver.findElement(By.id("SignInForm"));

    if (signInForm.isDisplayed())
        System.out.println("Sign in form is displayed");

    WebElement username;

    username = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder=\"Email or username\"]"));
```

It manages to find the My Ebay link, and verifies that the sign in form exists but the the username and password fields id's change after every refresh of the page.

The username cssSelector seems to be the problem??

EDIT:  I have been successful using XPath but this excercise was to make the cssSelector work as there is no reason in theory why it shouldn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the cssSelector locator with xpath and it is working fine with absolute xpath. Here is the modified code:

```
 WebDriver driver = null;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\vikas\\workspaceNeon\\Eclipse Soft\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.ebay.co.uk");

        WebElement myEbay = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My eBay"));
        myEbay.click();

        WebElement signInForm = driver.findElement(By.id("SignInForm"));

        if (signInForm.isDisplayed())
            System.out.println("Sign in form is displayed");

       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[4]/span[2]/input"));

       username.sendKeys("Vikas");
```

Comment: That works.  Appreciated! However, I was trying to make this work using CSS.  I am not sure as to the reason for the changing of the field ids on refresh.  XPath is quite brittle so trying to avoid!

Comment: Usually, the id's are unique but in this case, it is dynamic. It is really odd to see the dynamic id locator.

Comment: @Dean Your Question doesn't mentions anything about your specific preference to CSS. Consider accepting the best fit Answer and raise a new Question as per your new requirement. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think you are right DebanjanB!  I wasn't clear about what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Select all inputs as a list and search for the right one:

```
// fld seems to be the class of the input field but looking at all input elements should work too
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.className("fld")); 
for (WebElement input: inputs) { 
    if (inputs.getAttribute("placeholder") == "Email or username") {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the inputs.getAttribute to input.getAttribute as it wouldn't compile.  And tried using input.sendKeys("username"); within the if statement of the loop but still didn't manage to show the text within the username field.  Strangely, there were no failures within the console either?

Comment: I tried using input.sendKeys("username"); within the if statement of the loop but still didn't manage to show the text within the username field. Strangely, there were no failures within the console either?

Comment: Could you try again with the following selector?: By.cssSelector("input")

Comment: DasEarl, I am a little unsure as to what you mean? There are 56 occurrences on the render of my eBay site?  Really appreciate your input!

Comment: I meant the code above but with this:

List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input"));

Because there shouldn't be so many elements containing that placeholder

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work either!  Everything points to the placeholder cssSelector but it doesn't!  Confusing!  XPath works as below but not the cssSelector, perhaps will try css but me thinks the same result.

Answer (score 0):

if the username and password webelements changes frequently find div section in the page using xpath and get the exact xpath of username weblement.

Hope this help..